# Add to tutorials that roslaunch adds data-tail to args

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I started my node via roslaunch and discovered a datatail in the last two arguments, I did not now about (used kinetic). This was misleading because I checked for the min args required and therefore not failed hiding the missing args with the ones below. Could someone add this to the tutorials.

```
argv[10] = 1
argv[11] = __name:=sensor_binder
argv[12] = __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/063c83b2-5491-11e6-8f9d-8ca9827a5146/sensor_binder-4.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240621/add-to-tutorials-that-roslaunch-adds-data-tail-to-args/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an implementation detail that is normally handled by `ros::init()` and `rospy.init_node()`, so it would be clutter in the beginner tutorials.

There are a lot of other tutorials on the ROS wiki; which tutorial do you think this information should be included in?

These arguments are documented in the full ROS documentation on the [remapping arguments](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) page.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-07-28**:
I guess [roslaunch node](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node) would be ok with including your remapping link. Also one could emphasize the output on screen setting to let nodes talk to the terminal output.